# How to concatenate two descending arraylists made from user input into one (merging) while removing any repeats?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public void main()
{
    System.out.println();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer>nums1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer>nums2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer>numsFinal = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Merger.");
    System.out.println("Enter number of times to merge: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int o = 0, p = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);  
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);              
        System.out.println("Enter the first list of descending positive values followed by any letter when finished: (ex. 1 2 3 4 5 y)");
        while(input1.hasNextInt()){
            nums1.add(input1.nextInt());      
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the second list of descending positive values followed by any letter when finished: (ex. 6 7 8 9 10 p)"); 
        while(input2.hasNextInt()){
            nums2.add(input2.nextInt());      
        }     
        while(nums1.get(o)<nums2.get(o)||nums1.get(o)==nums2.get(p)){
            numsFinal.add(nums1.get(o));
            o++;
            while(nums2.get(p)<nums1.get(o)||nums2.get(p)==nums1.get(o)){
                numsFinal.add(nums2.get(p));
                p++;
            }                  
        }  
        System.out.println(numsFinal);
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I can seem to grasp the area where you traverse through both arraylists.  Help Appreciated!  I finished the part where the user's inputted values are stored into two separate arrays.  The merging into a third array is what is troublesome.

Ex input: 1 2 3 4 5
end of first input
          5 7 9 11 13
end of second input
  output: 1 2 3 4 5 7 9 11 13

Comment: Add them to a Set? Actually, why not just add all the inputs into a single set directly?

Comment: Your example shows ascending positive values, not descending.